# How to compute quaternion from max and min coordinate values of the Cube?

Tags: c++, ros, quaternions, vertex

I am facing some problem in creating the orientation of a cube (Bounding Box of the detected objects in ROS). I know the max and min coordinate values (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax). So, I can easily find the vertex of the objects Bounding BOX (Cube) which are

```
[xmin ymin zmin; 
 xmax ymin zmin; 
 xmax ymax zmin; 
 xmin ymax zmin;
 xmin ymin zmax; 
 xmax ymin zmax; 
 xmax ymax zmax;
 xmin ymax zmax]
```

Now how can I create the quaternion from these vertex in order to get the orientation of the bounding box? I know that a quaternion is a set of 4 numbers, [x y z w], which represents rotations the following way:

```
// RotationAngle is in radians
x = RotationAxis.x * sin(RotationAngle / 2)
y = RotationAxis.y * sin(RotationAngle / 2)
z = RotationAxis.z * sin(RotationAngle / 2)
w = cos(RotationAngle / 2)
```

How to get the RotationAxis and RotationAngle when knowing the vertex of the object (in my case is a cube or 3D rectangle)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(I don't know what ROS is, but here's an abstract discussion of your question.)

First of all, a "rotation" starts from a "from" state and ends at a "to" state. You know your "to" state, but you'll have to specify the "from" state. Let's assume your box starts at a default state, with one corner at (0, 0, 0) and another at (1, 1, 1).

This default box state, like your final one is an "axis-aligned" box. Now, the box might have rotated 90, 180, or 270 degrees, but if different faces of the box are not distinct from each other, this might not matter. This scenario will have a 0-degree rotation, and the quaternion representing this rotation is trivially calculated to be (0, 0, 0, 1). You'll still need scale and translation (which are also trivial to compute) to get from that default state to your BB, but no rotation.

Now, if the faces are actually different, then we'll indeed have a rotation. Let's call it an "axis-aligned rotation" or AAR, which can take a default box to any one of 24 different states. Think of it like this: the axis of rotation can be any of the 6 basis vectors in either direction (+x, -x, +y, -y, +z, -z), and the angle can be 0, 90, 180, or 270 degrees (6 * 4 is 24!)

Each case, when you think about it like that, completely defines a rotation quaternion which is trivial to construct. The problem then, becomes finding with of the 24 rotations we have.

I can think of two mental models for this: either pick one "front" face and one "top" face for your box and find out where they ended up in the "to" state (6 places for "front" and 4 places for "top".) Or you can pick an "origin" vertex and a "neighbor" vertex and find where they ended up (8 places for "origin" and 3 places for "neighbor".) In either case, you probably would have a 24-entry table to pre-calculated quaternions, which you will choose from based on your "rotation".

Answer (score 0):

The way you created your bounding box by using the minimum and maximum values leads to a bounding box aligned to the x, y, and z axes. Thus, it doesn't have any rotation and its quaternion would be [0, 0, 0, 1].

Getting the rotation matrix of randomly oriented cubes or rectangles is not complicated if you know which vertex relates to which corner of the cube/ rectangle. Then you can just use two perpendicular edges as the x and y axes in the objects coordinate frame. After normalizing these vectors you can create the z axis in the object frame by building the cross product of the x and y vectors. The columns of the 3x3 rotation matrix are these three vectors:

```
    | x_0  y_0  z_0 |
R = | x_1  y_1  z_1 |
    | x_2  y_2  z_2 |
```

You can search the internet for resources to get the rotation axis and quaternion from the rotation matrix.

For general objects, you can use the same method if you have the vertices of points on two perpendicular axes in the object coordinate frame. If you don't know the corespondig point in the object frame for your vertices, it gets more complicated. If your vertices are uniformly covering your object (e.g., vertices from 3D cameras or laser scans), you can use Principal Component Analysis to find the principal axes of the vertices. These axes form the columns of the rotation matrix (make sure the principal axes form a right-handed fram, i.e., the determinat of the rotation matrix is +1).

If these methods also don't apply to you, you could search for pose estimation methods in the context of point clouds (e.g.: Point Cloud Library [PCL](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl), [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/)).

Comment: But still if I know the 8 vertex then I can create the cube. And this cube must have some orientation. How can I get the  rotation matrix and how should I know which vertex relates to which corner of the cube/ rectangle.?

Comment: If you create the cube with the 8 vertices mentioned in your question, its edges will be parallel to the x, y and z axes. Without any further information or constraint, no rotation, i.e., a unity matrix as rotation matrix, is as good as any other rotation which transforms the edges of a cube to be parallel to the x, y and z axes. As mentioned in the other answer, you have several rotations leading to a similar result (a cube with its edges parallel to x, y and z axes). So additional constraints or assumptions could help you narrow this down. But you didn't mention any such constraints.

Comment: But I know the 8 corner points (x,y,z) of that cube. So it must have orientation. Correct, Knowing the 8 corner coordinate points of any cube , from there can be find its orientation. Am I correct?

Comment: Of corse the cube has an orientation (unit matrix is also a rotatio) . The problem is, that the orientation is not unique: Rotation is part of a transformation from an initial position to the final position. If you don't know the initial orientatian of the cube, it is not clear which of the 24 possible rotations to choose.

Comment: So why are you interested in the orientation of an axis-aligned bounding box, anyway?

Comment: Im working on pick and place project. And also working on collision detection,  so Im using CNN and deep learning for object detection. From object detector (yolo darknet_ros ) im getting the bounding box. So if i have to pick or place the object I need to know its orientation . So as Yolo is giving me the min and max I was thinking from there to get the orientation. But looks like it not possible. I think first need to get the ROI, then  use clustering method combined with region growing algorithm.Then sing a Gaussian Mixture Model. For that I need point clouds

Comment: so how to get that initial orientatian of the cube?

Comment: So your problem is to find the 6D pose (position and orientation) of the objects you are picking. This is not possible by using the axis-aligned bounding box returned by YOLO (e.g., similar bounding boxes, different orientations: |/| |\|). You can, however, use this bounding box to select only the part of the point cloud containing the object for further processing and pose estimation.

Comment: yes yes. I know So i have two options. First YOLO for select the ROI of the point clouds for further processing. Second, use 6D object detector,  but so far Im not familiar with any ready many solution that can give me the 6D Pose. Do you know any? And sorry one more question. What if my object are always aligned with one of the axis (let we say z-axis), can I use YOLO  without further processing the point cloud to get the position and orientation of the objects(as they are always touching the ground and only differs in the two axis orientation)

Comment: I successfully worked with the GASD descriptors. However, those require (segmented) point clouds that contain only one object instance and no background. As for your other question: As the YOLO bounding boxes are aligned to all axes (x, y, z) you could only measure rotations by 90, 180 degrees around the axes.
If you know that the objects always touch the ground (i.e. not on a pile), you could maybe use 2D template matching techniques (OpenCV has some methods build in for this).

Answer (score 0):

Code (from the tutorial) for the extraction of the OBB:

```
pcl::MomentOfInertiaEstimation <pcl::PointXYZ> feature_extractor;
feature_extractor.setInputCloud (cloud);
feature_extractor.compute ();

pcl::PointXYZ min_point_OBB;
pcl::PointXYZ max_point_OBB;
pcl::PointXYZ position_OBB;
Eigen::Matrix3f rotational_matrix_OBB;
Eigen::Vector3f major_vector, middle_vector, minor_vector;
Eigen::Vector3f mass_center;

feature_extractor.getOBB (min_point_OBB, max_point_OBB, position_OBB, rotational_matrix_OBB);
feature_extractor.getEigenVectors (major_vector, middle_vector, minor_vector);
feature_extractor.getMassCenter (mass_center);
```

So to get the final OBB - The coordinates:

```
Eigen::Vector3f p1 (min_point_OBB.x, min_point_OBB.y, min_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p2 (min_point_OBB.x, min_point_OBB.y, max_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p3 (max_point_OBB.x, min_point_OBB.y, max_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p4 (max_point_OBB.x, min_point_OBB.y, min_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p5 (min_point_OBB.x, max_point_OBB.y, min_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p6 (min_point_OBB.x, max_point_OBB.y, max_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p7 (max_point_OBB.x, max_point_OBB.y, max_point_OBB.z);
Eigen::Vector3f p8 (max_point_OBB.x, max_point_OBB.y, min_point_OBB.z);

p1 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p1 + position;
p2 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p2 + position;
p3 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p3 + position;
p4 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p4 + position;
p5 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p5 + position;
p6 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p6 + position;
p7 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p7 + position;
p8 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p8 + position
```

Bu `rotational_matrix_OBB` how to get?

Comment: Im using ZED Depth Camera. So can I apply Principal Component Analysis to find the principal axes of the vertices ? So how to get the principal axes of the vertices.? So after that can you get the rotation matrix? But in PCA tutorial I have major_value, middle_value, minor_value; then   Eigen::Vector3f major_vector, middle_vector, minor_vector; and   Eigen::Vector3f mass_center; How to get them?